# GitHub Actions - How to trim a string in a condition?

Tags: github-actions

How can I trim a string in a condition in GitHub actions workflow?
In the following example, the comment can contains accidentally spaces and new lines. I want to trim the spaces in `github.event.comment.body`:

```
steps:
  - name: "Check CLA signed"
    if: github.event.comment.body == 'I have read the CLA Document and I hereby sign the CLA'
```

Comment: show alt versions of `github.event.comment.body`, what's the no option or is it empty etc *I have not read the CLA Document and I hereby did not sign the CLA*?

Comment: btw you don't need to trim anything, contains(github.event.comment.body, 'I have read the CLA Document') would work, presuming that's whats set only when its chosen

Comment: github.event.comment.body can contain the string with another words as well. That's the reason I can't use contains.

Comment: make your own action which uses natural language classification like Naive Bayes or such AI to determine if, *yeash I do accept your thingie bob* is true or add a bunch of different matched ones.. or ask them to type the specific sentence, and reject for everything else (i think you can use multiple ifs but should prob do in a custom action)

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Skip to the end for a better answer.

I believe [GitHub Actions expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions) are very limited to checking basic things in a workflow, rather than offering programming capabilities.

If you need to go the route of checking different ways of writing a message, your best option is to run a check against the string in a step:

```yaml
steps:
  ...
  - name: Check if person has accepted and signed CLA
    shell: python
    run: |
      import sys

      def check_user_accepted_and_signed(text):
        """Some complex natural language processing will go here"""
      
      comment = '''${{ github.event.comment.body }}'''
      if not check_user_accepted_and_signed(comment):
        sys.exit(1)  # This will abort the job
  - name: Not accepted or signed
    if: ${{ failure() }}
    run: optionally do something if the check fails
  - name: Move on if the check passed
    run: ...
```

In the code above, you could also replace the inline Python snippet with a script call from your code base, for a cleaner code:

```yaml
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Check if person has accepted and signed CLA
    run: ./scripts/check-accepted-signed-cla.sh '${{ toJSON(github.event.comment.body) }}'
    # Single quotes and JSON string prevents bad whitespace interpretation
```

#### Simpler is usually better

IMHO though, you'd be better off -- and safer! -- doing simple things. Here's an idea:

1. Set up your GitHub repository with a default pull request body containing a checkbox, for example:

   ```markdown
   Write your description.
   ---
   - [ ] I have read the CLA and hereby sign it.
   ```
2. In your workflow, check for that checkbox and fail if it's not checked. [Shopify/task-list-checker](https://github.com/Shopify/task-list-checker) can be of great help here!

Comment: alternatively you can use shell: bash, run: if [[ ${{ github.event.comment.body }}' ~= 'some text' ]]

Answer (score -3):

You can find all functions that github actions support [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#functions)

I think you can use contains function for cover your case

Comment: Thanks, but "contains" is not exactly what I look for. There is no "trim" function in the documentation. I need a different solution.

Comment: look like you need some step before that will use 'shell: bash' and you will prepare env variable that you will use in your expression.
This should help you
[link](https://github.community/t/if-expression-with-context-variable/16558/5) check it please